# how to close a "BUY" position in scalping perpetual futures in binance API

Tags: python

What is the Binance endpoint to close a "buy" entry operation in process in perpetual futures scalping, using rules that are included in a script (bot) to operate in real time in the Binance API?

close a "BUY" type entry position in the Binance API.
I need to know the precise instructions to achieve this, as soon as the rules stipulated in my script (bot) are met. I can send my code

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could place an SELL order with the same amount, it can close your BUY position after it's filled.